# How to determine "real world" x, y coordinates from kinect depth data?

Tags: c#, kinect

The depth values returned by the kinect sensor correspond to the real world z distance (in mm) from the xy-plane. So far I can't find anything in the latest sdk that returns anything similar for the x and y coordinates. Is this provided in the sdk? Failing that, what would be a good way of computing x and y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use KinectSensor.MapDepthToSkeletonPoint method which return a SkeletonPoint. The sample code can be

```
using (DepthImageFrame depthimageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (depthimageFrame == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            pixelData = new short[depthimageFrame.PixelDataLength];

            depthimageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);

            for (int x = 0; x < depthimageFrame.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < depthimageFrame.Height; y++)
                {
                        SkeletonPoint p = sensor.MapDepthToSkeletonPoint(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30, x, y, pixelData[x + depthimageFrame.Width * y]);                        
                }
            }

        }
```